# Get schema of stored procedure which returned error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, error-handling, database-schema

I have several procedures with same name but in different schemas. When these procedures raise an error, it is possible in parent procedure (which is calling these nested stored procedures) get schema of the procedure which raised an error ? For example i can get name from `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` but is there some option to get also SCHEMA ? Because otherwise i am not sure which exactly procedure throwed an error if there are many with same name.

I guess this feature is still missing 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124627/schema-not-reported-in-the-error-procedure-function

but is there some workaround for this ?

Comment: in the `error_procedure()` documentation page there is a comment about this dated at May 25, 2017, well over 10 years after 2008 version was released....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible solutions I can think of:

- Renaming each Stored Procedure so that they have different names in the different schemas.
- Adding some debugging output to the Stored Procedures so that when they are being executed, you can see which one was in progress when your error occurred.
- Running the SQL Profiler to see what is being called at the time your error occurs.

However, these are coming more from the perspective of trying to troubleshoot an issue you're having right now, rather than building in some error handling for potential future troubleshooting. You could always get these Stored Procedures to write some log files to disk somewhere so you can interrogate those logs when an error is experienced perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no 100% Workaround for this limitation in SQL-Server.
Shame on the MSSQL Dev Team for not rectifying this, well over a Decade later.
It should be as simple as adding a New Function like `ERROR_ProcedureSchema()` or `ERROR_PROCID()`.
Here is a revived Post Requesting this Feature from way back in May of 2005:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894584-schema-not-reported-in-the-error-procedure-functio

I prefer to Log as much detail as possible about Exceptions I capture in my custom Error Handling Logic.
This is the best I could come up with to find the Schema Name:

```
DECLARE @Error_ProcSchemaName nVarChar(128)--Leave as Null if found in more than 1 Schema.
--Only Populate the @Error_ProcSchemaName if it Belongs to 1 Schema. - 04/08/2019 - MCR.
SELECT @Error_ProcSchemaName = S.name
  FROM sys.objects as O
  JOIN sys.schemas as S
    ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT O.name[ObjectName], COUNT(*)[Occurrences]
      FROM sys.objects as O
     GROUP BY O.name
  ) AS Total
    ON Total.ObjectName = O.name
 WHERE O.name = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
   AND Total.Occurrences = 1
```

**Avoid** using anything like `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(ERROR_PROCEDURE()))` as the string you pass into `OBJECT_ID()` should already have the Schema in it (which `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` does not).
Otherwise it will default to your Default Schema, which (in most cases) is `dbo`.

Run this Query to View all your Object Names that are Reused across Schemas:

```
--View Object Names that Exist in Multiple Schemas: - 04/08/2019 - MCR.
SELECT S.name[SchemaName], O.name[ObjectName], Total.Occurrences,
       O.type[Type], O.type_desc[TypeDesc],
       O.object_id[ObjectID], O.principal_id[PrincipalID], O.parent_object_id[ParentID],
       O.is_ms_shipped[MS], O.create_date[Created], O.modify_date[Modified]
  FROM sys.objects as O
  JOIN sys.schemas as S
    ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT O.name[ObjectName], COUNT(*)[Occurrences]
      FROM sys.objects as O
     GROUP BY O.name
  ) AS Total
    ON Total.ObjectName = O.name
 WHERE Total.Occurrences > 1
 ORDER BY [ObjectName], [SchemaName]
```

If you only have a few Objects (Sprocs and Triggers) that overlap, then you might be okay not knowing the Schema as it may be obvious where it originated from.
However, if this is not the case, then you may need to either:

1. Change the Name of the Sproc/Trigger to make it Unique.
   This option goes against the very fiber of my being.
2. If you are using Advanced Error Handling, then manually add the Schema of your Sproc/Trigger with `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)`
   in your Catch-Block when logging the Error.

Note: These options may not be possible due to the use of 3rd Party Sprocs you are not allowed to edit.
When Troubleshooting with multiple Sprocs/Triggers that share the same Name, you might be able to write a Custom Wrapper-Sproc to call your 3rd Party Sproc, then Log any exception thrown in your Wrapper to know exactly which Schema/Sproc caused it.

**The Code Smell:**
If you have multiple Sprocs/Triggers with the same name spread across various Schemas
     then I would call that a "*Code Smell*".
Meaning, your Architecture is flawed.
You may not be properly encapsulating your logic for reuse.
There will be times when a name overlaps Schemas, but this should be rare and by coincidence only.

**Misappropriating Schemas for Handling Multi-Tenant / UserGroup Access:**
If you are trying something Multi-Tenant (storing data from different Organizations/UserGroups in the same Database and preventing them from seeing eachother's info) and running almost the same logic in each Schema that shares the Object Name, then that's a Design Problem.
You should have your data in Different Databases if Users will be accessing it directly
     or have a `TenantID` or `UserGroupID` you always pass in and filter on everywhere when Users will be accessing from a Custom Application.